# Upperbound for Covariance Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

Suppose $X_t \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a vector valued time series, or in other words a vector valued stochastic process indexed by $t \in \mathbb{Z}$. Assume for the moment that $X_t$ is (weakly) stationary with $EX_t=0$, $E\|X_t\|^2<\infty$, and let

$$
C_h = E[X_0 X_h^\top]
$$
denote the autocovariance matrix at lag $h$. What I wish to show is that

$$
\|C_h\|_2 \le \|C_0\|_2,
$$
or find a counterexample to this statement. Here $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the Hilbert-Schmidt Norm:
$$\|A\|_2^2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^d a_{i,j}^2. $$

So far all I can show is the weaker statement that
$$
\|C_h\|_2 \le trace(C_0).
$$

To see this, we have by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for expectation and stationarity that
$$
\|C_h\|_2^2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^d (E[X_{0,i}X_{h,j}])^2 \le  \sum_{i,j=1}^d E[X_{0,i}^2]E[X_{h,j}^2] = \sum_{i,j=1}^d E[X_{0,i}^2]E[X_{0,j}^2] =[trace(C_0)]^2.
$$
Part of me believes that this bound must be sharp, i.e. there is a counter example where $\|C_h\|_2 > \|C_0\|_2$, but I really have no idea! Whatever simple examples I have tried have $\|C_h\|_2 \le \|C_0\|_2$, for instance vector autoregressive processes. Any help/advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I share your belief that the C-S inequality suggests a counter-example must exist.  IIRC, C-S inequality achieves equality iff the two random variables are identical (up to scaling, and almost surely?).  In your context, this would mean every $X_{t,k}$ is the same (almost surely?).  But in that case, every entry of the covariance matrix equals $E[X^2_{0,0}]$ and so the norm equals the trace.

Comment: Good point @antkam  , that is where I'm stuck too! My reasoning is that since $\|x\|_2 \le \|x\|_1$ with strict inequality possible, one can easily construct a matrix $C_0$ so that $\|C_0 \|_2 < trace(C_0)$ (diagonal matrices for example). Now somehow you construct $X_t$ so that $\|C_h\|$ fits in the gap. Not getting anywhere with it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the spectral measure representation for the covariance matrix. In a nutshell, you have, $C_h=\int A(t)e^{iht}\,d\mu(t)$ where $A(t)$ are positive semidefinite and $\mu$ is some non-negative scalar measure on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Then ${\rm trace}[C_h^*C_h]=\Re\iint e^{ih(t-s)}{\rm trace}[A(t)A(s)]\,d\mu(t)d\mu(s)$. However ${\rm trace}[A(t)A(s)]={\rm trace}[A(t)^{1/2}A(s)A(t)^{1/2}]\ge 0$ for all $t,s$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @fedja! One thing I cannot see from this is why this implies that $\|C_h\| \le \|C_0\|$. Could you elaborate on that by providing some more details?

Comment: @LostStatistician18 What exactly is unclear? $\|C_h\|^2={\rm trace}[C_h^*C_h]$ and if you integrate a positive function against an oscillating one, the largest integral is obtained when there is no oscillation, i.e., when $h=0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: That helps! I didn't make that step when I read it initially. Awesome! Thanks a lot @fedja, the bounty is yours! Nice and elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the claim is true when you have a WSS process where $E[XY^\top]$ is symmetric. I have not shown it for general $C_h$. We will show two things:

$$\frac{E[X X^\top] + E[Y Y^\top]}{2} \geq \frac{E[XY^\top] + E[YX^\top]}{2}$$

and

if $A > B$ are symmetric PSD matrices, then $||A|| > ||B||$.

Given these, your result should immediately follow (Just substitute $Y = X_h$ and use WSS to make sure variances and covariances are equal; you need symmetry in your autocorrelation function to merge the sum on the RHS into the one you want.)

For the first one, just multiply left and right by $u$, and then use the elementary Young's inequality, i.e. the fact that $E[(u^\top X)(Y^\top u)] \leq    
\frac{1}{2} (E[(u^\top X)^2] + E[(Y^\top u)^2])$

For the second, note that when you have three symmetric PSD matrices, A,B, C, and $A > B$, then we have

tr($BC$) $\leq $ tr($AC$)

which you can show by rewriting your matrices in their eigenvector form.

Thus, we have

$||B||^2$ = tr($B^\top B$) $\leq $ tr($A^\top B$) $\leq$ tr($A^\top A$) = $||A||^2$

Comment: Thanks for the answer @E-A! The only thing I'm confused about is the following-- it is clear using Young's inequality that $C_0-C_h$ is positive definite, i.e. $C_0\ge C_h$, but now the result only seems to follow from this argument when $C_h$ is positive definite and symmetric, which it need not be. Isn't that a problem here?

Comment: Yes, I think it could be. That is why I asked for a symmetric autocorrelation function (and wanted to symmetrize for the first half of the proof so that at least that part goes through regardless) for that trace inequality to go through. Don't real WSS have symmetric autocorrelation functions though? I tried googling for a source of that statement, but could not find one. If you can bring a non-symmetric WSS process, then I might be able to give a counter-example to your overall claim.

Comment: Well it is easy to show that $C_h=C_{-h}^\top$, but $C_h$ itself need not be positive definite or symmetric. Example: let $w_{t,1}$ and $w_{t,2}$ be IID random variables with mean zero, finite variance. Define $X_{t,1}= w_{t,1}- w_{t-1,2}$, $X_{t,2}=w_{t-1,2}$. Then

Comment: $C_1$ has just a $-1$ in the upper right hand (1,2) entry, and is zero otherwise. This matrix is not positive definite nor symmetric. You could rig it up too so that it even has negative eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Hm, I will think of some counterexamples to the statement \frac{1}{2} A^2 + B^2> AB or show that it is true for general matrices then. If you come up with anything related to that, please add them as a comment or update your post. I will leave my answer up but put a clear disclaimer that it works for symmetric WSS processes only.

Comment: Thanks for your help @E-A! I will continue to think about this too and if I have any good ideas I'll add them to the comment chain.